# Blazor - Index was out of range though previous checks show it is not

Tags: c#, blazor

Since alterations can happen during the component rendering, even if you do checks before trying to index an array it can still error out.
`if (AList[inumberthatchanges].Count > 0)` still throws despite previous checks because the inumberthatchanges can still technically change in-between and it does sometimes. How would you go about fixing this type of situation? This selected I changes frequently and used quite often throughout the site. Normally I would just do a try catch and ignore such a situation, but you cannot do that with Blazor inside of HTML rendering.

```
@if (AList.Count > 0 
     && AList.Count >= inumberthatchanges 
     && AList[inumberthatchanges].Count > 0)
{
    if (AList[inumberthatchanges].Count > 0)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: This condition `AList.Count >= innumberthatchanges` should be `AList.Count > innumberthatchanges`

Comment: It looks like this is the answer, I forgot to count the 0. Amateur mistake heh....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This condition `AList.Count >= innumberthatchanges` should be `AList.Count > innumberthatchanges`.

Because `Count of array starts from 1`. But the index starts from zero...`enter code here`

Comment: ok, I deleted mine.